# Creating a VBA macro which can be ran on multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a macro which calls other macros (like the one below) and applies them to specified sheets.

I think the problem is that my previously made macros in which it calls upon isn't coded correctly to be applied to sheets it's not actively on.

Here is my code:

```
Sub limits_Monitoring_bores()

        Dim sht As Worksheet, lastRow As Long
        Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet

'Name columns appropriately


 With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    .Cells(1, 4).Value = "Min"
    .Cells(1, 5).Value = "Max"
    .Cells(1, 7).Value = "20th Percentile"
    .Cells(1, 8).Value = "80th Percentile"
    .Cells(1, 10).Value = "20th Percentile"
    .Cells(1, 11).Value = "80th Percentile"

End With

        lastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        sh.Range("D2:D" & lastRow).Value = "=6"
        sh.Range("E2:E" & lastRow).Value = "=8.5"
        sh.Range("G2:G" & lastRow).Value = "=PERCENTILE(F:F,0.2)"
        sh.Range("H2:H" & lastRow).Value = "=PERCENTILE(F:F,0.8)"
        sh.Range("J2:J" & lastRow).Value = "=PERCENTILE(I:I,0.2)"
        sh.Range("K2:K" & lastRow).Value = "=PERCENTILE(I:I,0.8)"
```

Comment: Sorry don't understand that, but `sh` is not defined. Use `Option Explicit`.

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)` probably needs to become `sht`, and then there's no reason for `End With` to be where it's at - should be at the bottom, with any further `sht` calls made against the `With` block variable. And `sh` is a typo, heed @SJR's advice and stick `Option Explicit` at the top of the file & fix the code accordingly (code won't compile with undeclared variables, *and that is a very very good thing*)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I get a "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" at the `Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` line

Comment: `Worksheets` is a collection of `Worksheet` objects, of course you can't assign it to a `Worksheet` reference. You need to decide what single sheet you're working with.

Comment: But I want the macro to be applied to multiple specified sheets, as per my question

Comment: And where/how are these multiple sheets going to be specified? There are many, many ways to do this. A simple way would be to make your procedure take a `Worksheet` parameter and work off that parameter (hence why I keep insisting you change your code to work off a single worksheet variable), and have the calling code loop through the sheets you want to run it for, passing the sheets to the procedure at each iteration.

Comment: Another way could be to group the sheets you want to work with, and then work `With ActiveSheet` and have all sheets affected at once. The macro recorder does a great job at showing how that's done.

Comment: ended up going with the ```With ActiveSheet``` method using the macro recorder